# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS does not shutdown on HP Desktop

Tags: 20.04, shutdown, hp

When shutting down screen goes black but power light does not go off.  I even left it overnight and the power light remained on.  [image: Output of Journalctl sudo journalctl -b -1 -e]

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Thanks

Comment: So far I haven't found a solution.  I submitted a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

If the HP desktop that you are using is similar to the All-in-One machines that I've supported in the past, then you may need to make a slight modification to your Grub file to disable ACPI warnings, which can keep a computer active.

Here's how you can do it:

0. Open a Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Edit your `/etc/default/grub` file with `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo {editor of choice} /etc/default/grub
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{editor of choice}` with your editor of choice.</sup>
2. Find the line that starts `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add `acpi=off` to the end of the line, but inside the quotes. For example:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
   ```
3. Save the file and exit
4. Update Grub:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** This step is important. If you skip it, then the change will not be applied no matter how many times you reboot.</sup>
5. Restart your computer

Hopefully this allows your rest-deprived HP to shut down properly

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately this did not fix the problem.  I edited the file and updated grub as you suggested. Can I supply any information to you that might help find and fix the issue?

Comment: I just noticed after the above change my sound stopped working.  I removed the edit, updated grub and my sound came back after rebooting.

Comment: It didn't work. Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, Kernal version 5.13.0-27-generic, GNOME version 3.36.8.
Also, I'm pretty sure this occurred with the firmware update that came with the usual Linux updates last week.